# how to use might for past sentences

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs

I wrote:

> It was a step toward independence and get rid of foreign interference, but it **might went** too ideological on this ground.

versus.

> It was a step toward independence and get rid of foreign interference, but it probably went too ideological on this ground.

> It was a step toward independence and get rid of foreign interference, but it might go too ideological on this ground.

Which of them is correct according to the meaning I want to convey? I don't know why, but I like to use "might" and prefer it to "probably" but then again I like to use "went" rather "go" because "might went" to me is something that happened in the past. I'm not sure if "might go" still means that the event happened in the past.

Answer (score 3):

It was a step toward independence and get rid of foreign interference, but it might went too ideological on this ground.

should be:

It **was** a step toward independence and **got** rid of foreign interference, but it **might have been** too ideological.

Past tense of might:

- might have been
- might have seen
- might have gone
- might have walked

might + have + past participle

Comment: But have been or have gone convey that the activity continued to present, what if I want to say this sentence for example to ancient Egypt?

Comment: @Ahmad Please just believe me: might can only be used in the past tense for things that did not happen or did not exist and it is written as I have shown. Also, might have gone or might have done or might have [past participle] is not a present perfect tense. It has nothing to do with an activity that continues into the present.

Answer (score 0):

It was a step toward independence and getting rid of foreign interference, but it might have gone too ideological on this ground.

Comment: Pay attention to: getting rid of.                                                   ... towards +noun/gerind